# Sort a mysql table using php,ajax and jquery

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Ok here is the deal i am building a messaging system by php,ajax,jquery and mysql i add the new message and i add in 2 rows now what i want to do is to send an ajax request to server and recieve an updated version of the table but sorted 
So how can i do so

//here i add and call the message the message

```
function addMsg()
    {
      //alert(post);
        $.get("db.php",$('form').serialize(),
           function(data){
            getMsg(data);},"html");
}
```

function getMsg(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            $("#t1").append(data);
}
//php

".""."".$row["col"]."".$row["col"]."".$row["col"].""; 
       }

?>

//Now for sorting 
//javascript

```
function sort()
    {
        $.ajax({
          url: "sort.php",
          dataType: "text",
          success: function(data){
          $("t1").text(data);
              }

        });

    }
```

//php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col desc");

```
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
           {     
           echo "<tbody><tr><td>"."&#8226;"."</td><td>".$row["col"]."</td><td>".$row["col"]."</td><td></td><td></td><tr><td></td><td colspan='4'>".$row["col"]."</td></tr></tbody>"; 
           }
```

?>

Comment: It might make your question easier to read for everyone if you used a period once in a while. =]

Comment: Also, a few lines of your source code are formatted incorrectly. You need to put 4 spaces in front of "function getMsg(data)..." and "$result = mysql_query(..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ORDER BY when you do the SELECT. Check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html